# OpenCV : CMake Error at /opencv-2.4.9/cmake/cl2.cpp

Tags: opencv, cmake

CMake Build error:
I configured CMake and run `make` command to build `Opencv`. It gets stopped when It reached to 82%.

error is :

```
CMake Error at /opencv-2.4.9/cmake/cl2.cpp : 50 (string):
string does not recognize sub-command MD5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself fix the issue by commenting the line caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade CMake.
You can also try to comment the line out and try again!

Comment: It is already an updated version. I executed this command: `sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui` to install cmake